# VS Code через N-e количество часов сильно грузит процессор и зависает

Tags: visual-studio-code

С утра начинаю писать код в VS Code. Примерно через 6-8 часов внезапно нагрузка от редактора на процессор поднимается до 40% и редактор зависает. Приходится перезапускать. И так каждый день.

Как можно выяснить причину?

Предполагаю, что причина в одном из расширений. Но отключать их под одному не вариант, так как, во-первых, их довольно много (30-40 штук), во-вторых, как я уже написал, проблема проявляется не сразу.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была конкретно в версии 1.28. После установки инсайдерской 1.3 и стабильной 1.29 все стало нормально.